# WPF animated object collision detection, objects not displaying in position of intersection

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have rectangle shaped custom controls being animated on a path, 35 in total.
When a control stops, for what ever reason, I detect if any other controls overlap/intersect with it. If they do, I stop them.

To detect a collision, when a controls stops it triggers a DispatcherTimer to start. When the tick even triggers it does this.

- Pause all the storyboards that are currently running.
- Loop through every control and see if they intersect with the stopped control.
- If they do, then that control is also marked as stopped.
- Once loop is complete, any control that is not marked as stopped, I continue the storyboard.

Hopefully that logic sounds ok for the basics. This is the code for the detection part.

```
foreach (var ucPallet in Paellets)
{
    if(ucPallet.IsMoving)
       ucPallet.Storyboard.Pause(this);
}

for (var j = 0; j < Paellets.Count; j++)
{
    var movingBounds = Paellets[j].BoundsRelativeTo(AnimationCanvas);
    var stoppedBounds = stoppedPallet.BoundsRelativeTo(AnimationCanvas);

    if (stoppedBounds.IntersectsWith(movingBounds))
    {
       var pallet = movingPaellet[j]; // Breakpoint Here
       pallet.IsMoving = false;  
    }
}

foreach (var ucPallet in Paellets)
{
    if(ucPallet.IsMoving) // Only continue if not set to stop
       ucPallet.Storyboard.Resume(this);
}
```

For test purposes, I just made a simple path between 2 points, so there is a start and end. I create the controls in a loop, with a gap of about 250ms.
What should happen is that when the first control stops (Storyboard Complete), the others should stack up behind it. A Bit like cars coming to a stop at a traffic light.

The problem.
Visually, they are not stacking behind eachother they are all going to the end.

If I put a break point on the detection of an intersection (see Breakpoint Here in the above code), I can see the details of the bounds and it looks like the intersect is about 5 pixels.

With the assumption that the storyboard has paused, and I do not continue it, why does it visually not look the same as what the bounds say? i.e. I expect to see 1 control overlap the other by about 5 pixels, instead I see it is the same location and 1 control covers the other.

UPDATE 1:
Just a thought after submitting the question. I put a Console.WriteLine in every Storyboard.Complete EventHandler. In theory I should only see 1 (the first control) as the others are paused when they intersect. When I run I see they all complete. How can this happen if I have Paused them?

UPDATE 2:
Simple Project link to show the issue.
[PalletTest.Zip](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An4bv3TpvWfcjYIQt9RVUx6m7WA8SA)

Comment: The for loop iterates over ALL pallets; is is comparing the bounds of a pallet with its own bounds? It is hard to tell what is going on without a minimal, complete example that we can read/test.

Comment: I filter the list at first and remove the stopped pallet. Even if I never, for this test it shouldn't matter if it tests itself. All it would do is set IsMoving to false which it already is. i will try and create a simple version. The program itself is very big.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Added project example.

Answer (score 0):

To `Pause` a `StoryBoard`, you have to `Begin` it like this:

```
myStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
```

Did you? See [How to: Control a Storyboard After It Starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Update** after looking at the project:

The pallets are moving too fast. I've played around with your animations parms Setting the animation's Duration to 15 seconds results in a "perfect stack" as you expected and only one completed animation. Looks like with 2 seconds one animated step is too big, so the last step executed reahces the end of the path.

So there's nothing wrong with your code. So I just have a tiny suggestion for improvement: You can reduce the three for/foreach-loops to a single, where you set `IsMoving` and pause the animation. Here is a sample, that uses LINQ:

```
var stoppedPallets = this.Pallets.Where(p => !p.IsMoving).ToList();
var movingPallets = this.Pallets.Where(p => p.IsMoving).ToList();
foreach (var movingPallet in movingPallets)
{
   var movingBounds = movingPallet.BoundsRelativeTo(this.AnimationGrid);
   if (stoppedPallets.Any(
      p => p.BoundsRelativeTo(this.AnimationGrid).IntersectsWith(movingBounds)))
   {
      movingPallet.Storyboard.Pause(this);
      movingPallet.IsMoving = false;
   }
}
```

There is still some room for optimization, as the bounds of the stopped pallets are calculated for every moving pallet (this is true for the above and for your code).

Additionally, I would recommend moving as much of the pallet-initializing as possible to the `ucPallet` class.

Comment: Yes I did. I have added a project example in the question.

Comment: ah crap, Thanks for looking. I need it to run at what ever speed because the next phase of project is, apart from tidying up lol, to add animation controls. One of them being the animation speed which can run faster or slower.

Comment: but then you are in control of limiting max-speed

Comment: Yeah but customer requirements will need it to run faster. The program will simulate a period of time, say 6 hours. A user doesn't want to watch it in real time so will want to speed it up. I guess the only thing I can do is that when a collision is detected, I move the pallet into the correct position.